# assigning non-unique ID to a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {       "name": [
            "Hello Kitty",
            "Hello Puppy",
            "It is an Helloexample",
            "for stackoverflow",
            "Hello World",
        ],
    }
)
```

I want to add a column `my_id` which assigns the value starting from 1 onwards for every three records, i.e., for first three records the `my_id` column should get the value 1, then for next 3 it should get the value 2 and so on.

How can I do this in `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integer division by `3` with index values if default `RangeIndex`:

```
df['my_id'] = df.index // 3 + 1
```

If any index you can use helper array:

```
df['my_id'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 3 + 1
```

---

```
print (df)
                    name  my_id
0            Hello Kitty      1
1            Hello Puppy      1
2  It is an Helloexample      1
3      for stackoverflow      2
4            Hello World      2
```